# .NET Core with Autofac DI

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

I want to integrate `Autofac` to my API. Solution is split on several projects so that everything stays decoupled. I have set up my configure services like this:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    ...
    ...

    // Autofac
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<RouteRepository>().As<IRouteRepository>();

    builder.Populate(services);
    ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
}
```

However now with this code integrated, my API won't start anymore. If I start it in debug mode, I get no errors, but I don't get response either.

API landing route is pretty straightforward:

```
public IActionResult GetIndex()
{
    return Ok("You are seeing this because controller is working!");
}
```

Also, what might be connected to the problem is that `RouteRepository` takes one variable as an argument in the constructor and I don't know where can I define what will be passed through? There is no config file by default.

Comment: Does `ConfigureServices` call `services.AddMvc()` and `Configure` call `UseMvc()`?

Comment: Yeah, I just omitted it from the shown code as I thought it is not relevant

Comment: If your repository accepts a parameter in constructor, you have to define the dependency in startup: `builder.RegisterType<RouteRepositoryParameter>().As<IRouteRepositoryParameter>();`

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that you have one dependency for your `RouteRepository`, then you have to notify [`Autofac`](https://autofac.org/) container how to resolve that:

```
// singletone
builder.RegisterInstance(new TaskRepository())
   .As<ITaskRepository>();
// or instance based creation
builder.Register(c => new LogManager(DateTime.Now))
   .As<ILogger>();
```

Or `Autofac` couldn't resolve your type.